# What email header will GMail use to state the distribution list an email came from?

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-api, email-headers

For example:

- customer sends email to support@company.com
- support@company.com is a distribution list which automatically forwards the message further to mary@company.com and joseph@company.com
- My application subscribes to mail coming into mary@company.com and joseph@company.com using the GMail api: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get

When my application receives the Message from Google, where can I find the distribution list's address (support@company.com)?

I have tried reading emails received via distribution lists from the GMail api and inspecting their headers. But since I cannot find the official documentation on the topic, I do not know if my anecdotal experiment was comprehensive enough.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to retrieve the messages? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Hi! @LorenaGomez :) I would just be using the GMail API to retrieve messages: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/get

I would be following a request like so: 
`GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/labels/{id}`